# How to access submitted answers to Wolfram Challenges?

Tags: challenge-community

I've seen a lot of [interesting questions](https://challenges.wolfram.com/challenge/words-with-a-given-prefix) in the Wolfram Challenges [here](https://challenges.wolfram.com/), but I don't know how to look at some of their current best answered code.

I see a lot of participants providing a lot of fast code. What can I do to see the top three reference answers?

[image: screenshot of a leaderboard from one of the challenges]

Comment: Have a look around in this community: [how-can-i-tally-users-on-the-wolfram-challenges-leaderboard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183822/how-can-i-tally-users-on-the-wolfram-challenges-leaderboard) might do it already.

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke Thank you, but I'm more interested in the top ranked code, and I want to see their code.